# Video Viewer SharePoint 2019 On Premise

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, video

Does anyone has an idea how to play a video from a SharePoint Library in a WebPart for SharePoint 2019 On Prem?

Like **File Viewer** in SharePoint Online, but videos are not supported in SP2019 on prem.

Comment: Classic experience or modern experience? Did you try using "Embed" web part for this on modern experience?

Comment: Can you explore more

Comment: which experience? above solution with embed web part working for you?

Comment: Modern experience